# How can I generate a constant (JS) in Playwright without changes while passing all the tests

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I tried

```
const randomName = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(2);
export const NEW_PERSONALIZATION_NAME = randomName;
```

If the test is passed, everything is fine. If the test fails, the constant is generated again. Look at my screen
How can I solve this problem?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFV6E.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Workers are shutdown on a test failure, see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-parallel#worker-processes

Thats the reason why a new random value gets calculated on a test failure.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to solve this problem?